# How do i make the script auto-restart

Tags: php, linux, shell

How do i make the script auto-restart i think there is some issue in the last line .

```
#!/bin/bash

# a shell script that keeps looping until an exit code is given

php_command="php -q -f $1.php "
shift
nice $php_command $@
ERR=$?
..............
..............
exec $0 $@
```

I get the follwoing error `exec: 36: ss.sh: not found`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `set -e` and a simple `while` loop in bash:

```
#!/bin/sh

set -e

php_script=$1.php
shift

while true; do
    php $php_script $@
done
```

Once the PHP script returns an exit code of non-zero the bash script will stop. If you need to run any code after the loop is done, you can do this instead:

```
while php $php_script $@; do
    continue
done
```

Comment: cant i do anything other than while

Comment: You want a shell script that keeps looping; there are not many other methods to loop :) not sure what you mean?

Comment: ys i wnat it to keep looping but doen't  exec $0 $@ do the same thing some thing recursive functions

Comment: so this pice is the code for while loop  "while true; do php $php_script $@ done"

Comment: To be honest, as much as possible, I avoid recursion because our human minds are just too small to comprehend the complexities ;-) in any case, `exec $0 $@` doesn't work because of `shift`. You have to save `$@` into another variable before `shift`.

Comment: `shift` moves the arguments to the left, `$2` becomes `$1` etc., leaving `$0` in place.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than have the PHP script repeatedly executed, could this perhaps be changed to a loop within the PHP script itself?

Comment: i wnat to do it in shell script